# EaselJS passing parameters with events

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, easeljs, flash-ide

I am using Adobe Flash CC to create [EaselJS](http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/modules/EaselJS.html) output manipulating the HTML5 canvas. However there seems to be a massive oversight in the ability to pass parameters to event listeners.

The issue is that I offer multiple animation outputs for compatibility, one using EaselJS and one using [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/), however the interface that controls these remains the same, these are plain HTML elements with data stored in attributes that I wish to call functions written in the Flash IDE by triggering events and passing parameters.

I could easily find ways to avoid using `EventDispatcher` such as registering them with the root object and calling them directly with custom handlers. However I would rather keep my Flash IDE output as universally compatible as possible and not pollute object's namespaces I have little control over. I consider it a bad design pattern to write code in the Flash IDE that won't work without external aid.

Is there a way to pass parameters from an EaselJS event dispatcher to the listening events? I know `on()` provides a data parameter but that is useless as I need to pass different parameters to the same event depending upon user interaction.

Answer (score 1):

You can put any properties on an Event object that you want. When you dispatch an event, you can use a string like "complete" (which is better if you don't need parameters, since it won't generate an object if there are no listeners). If you have parameters, create a new `createjs.Event`, and put whatever properties on it that you want:

```
var event = new createjs.Event("complete");
event.time = new Date();
this.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Then you can inspect the event object in your handler.

```
myObject.addEventListener("complete", handler); // add a listener
function handler(event) {
    console.log(event.time);
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Note that if an EaselJS event is re-dispatched, then it is cloned, which will drop your custom properties. This shouldn't be a problem, unless you manually re-dispatch events, or if the event bubbles.

Comment: it doesent Works anumore since version 0.8

Comment: @DanielSantos - Can you clarify? This issue is almost a year old. If you are having trouble with something, please post a new issue. Thanks!

Comment: @DanielSantos Here is a quick fiddle that shows it working: http://jsfiddle.net/hfmm71oc/